# If $\int^{1}_{0} \frac{\tan^{-1}x}{x} dx = k \int^{\pi/2}_{0} \frac {x}{\sin x} dx$, find $k$.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

> **Problem**: If $$\int^{1}_{0} \frac{\tan^{-1} x}{x} dx = k \int^{\pi/2}_{0} \frac{x}{\sin x} dx,$$ find $k$.
>
> **Solution**: If we put $x=\tan t$ in $$\int^{1}_{0} \frac{\tan^{-1}x}{x} dx$$ then integral becomes $$\int^{\pi/4}_{0} \frac{t}{\tan t} \sec^2t \,dt$$ or may be we can do integration by parts.
>
> I have no idea about $\int^{\pi/2}_0 \frac {x}{\sin x} dx$ as $\int_{0}^{a} f(x) \ dx = \int_{0}^{a} f(a-x) \ dx$ method is not looking valid in above case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

From where you have left,

$$I=\int^{\frac{\pi}4}_0  \frac t {\tan t} \sec^2t dt=\int_0^{\frac\pi4}\frac t{\sin t\cos t}dt=\int_0^{\frac\pi4}\frac{2t}{\sin2t}dt$$ as $\sin2t=2\sin t\cos t$

Put $2t=u$

Comment: Then ans will be (1/2). Am I right ??

Comment: @rst, yes. Is the idea clear to you?

Comment: Yeah,thanks a lot